# How to set the capacity while creating table by invoking indexedTable function

Tags: sql, database, dolphindb

How to set the capacity while creating table by invoking indexedTable function?

I use indexedTable to create a table, the code is:

```
t1 = indexedTable(`sym`id, 1:0, `sym`id`val, [SYMBOL,INT,INT])
t2 = indexedTable(`sym`id, 100:0, `sym`id`val, [SYMBOL,INT,INT])
```

I find there is no difference in writing and querying data. So I wonder what's the role of capacity?

Answer (score 0):

The parameter "capacity" is a positive integer, showing the memory (in the number of records) allocated by the system for the table when the table is built. When the number of records exceeds the capacity, the system will first allocate a new memory space of 1.2~2 times the capacity, then copy the data to the new memory space, and finally release the original memory. For larger tables, the memory usage of such operations will be very high. Therefore, it is recommended to allocate a reasonable capacity in advance when building the table.